# Functional programming with lodash yields unexpected output

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm working on getting my head around functional programming and I have the following functions:

```
fp = lodash/fp, _ = lodash (not yet optimized)

// Reference functions 
const getAttributes = fp.getOr({}, `attributes`)
const toArray = fp.curry(input => _.isArray(input) ? [...input] : input ? [input] : [] )

const getTags = fp.flow(getAttributes(), fp.getOr([], 'tags'), toArray())
// returns ['tag 1', 'Tag 2', ...] or else an empty array.


const lowerString = fp.map( taxonomy => taxonomy ? taxonomy.toLowerCase() : '' )
// Used to normalize the tags to lowercase.


const normalizeTags = fp.flow(getTags(), (d) => {console.log(d); return d}, lowerString())
// My composed function that combines the two
```

The problem is that the result of that in-between `console.log()` and therefore the cause of my `lowerString()` error, is the original object that `getAttributes()` returns.

Comment: can you set us up a working example on Plunker or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're passing the results of calling `getAttributes`, `toArray`, `getTags`, and `lowerString` as arguments to `flow` instead of the functions themselves.

```
const getTags = fp.flow(getAttributes(), fp.getOr([], 'tags'), toArray())
```

vs

```
const getTags = fp.flow(getAttributes, fp.getOr([], 'tags'), toArray)
```

and

```
const normalizeTags = fp.flow(getTags(), (d) => {console.log(d); return d}, lowerString())
```

vs

```
const normalizeTags = fp.flow(getTags, (d) => {console.log(d); return d}, lowerString)
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that!